# Binning a list of numbers to a given window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following list example:

`[-8,-7,-6,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I need to bin it in the following way:
e.g. given `window=2`, we always start binning from 0 to left for negative numbers, and from 0 to right for positive numbers:

`[-4,-3,-3,-2,-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]`

e.g. given `window=3`:

`[-3,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]`

The bins are computed starting from the 0s. So I need to bin everything left and right to zero. Say, in `[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]` with `window=2`, I would bin the negative numbers in a step of 2. Let's reverse the list to start with 0 to help understand it better `[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]`, the result would be:

`[-1, -2] turns into a bin -> [-1,-1]`

`[-3, -4] -> [-2, -2]`

`[-5, ] -> [-5, ]]`

If I have both positive and negative numbers, I would first bin either the ones left to the most left 0 or right to the most right 0. Another example:

`list = [-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,3,4]`
`window=2`

So I need to bin `[-2,-1]` and `[1,2,3,4]`. They would turn into: `[-1,-1]` and `[1,1,2,2]`. The final list will be: `[-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2]`

I am on Python 3. My attempt at it, mostly pseudo-code:

```
def bin_positions(self, positions_list, bin_window):
    """ put relative positions into bins """

    binned_list = list()
    for index, element in enumerate(positions_list):
        if element == 0:
            # leave 0s untouched
            binned_list.append(element)
        elif element < 0:
            if index % bin_window == 0:
                # bin negative numbers
                pass
        elif element > 0:
            if index % bin_window == 0:
                # bin positive numbers
                pass
        # print(element, index)
    return binned_list
```

Explanation on why I need this, as requested:
I am working on an NLP task where I need to encode positional embeddings relative to a given word span of the main word or phrase in the sentence. In my example, word span of the main phrase is denoted by 0s. And a word to the left of it, is indexed as -1, to the right, as index 1 and so on. I need to bin those positions since I don't care how precisely far the words are from the main word, but only relatively. So, all 3 words to the left of the main word can be indexed as -1,-1,-1 if `window=3`.

Comment: Can you explain why and how this works?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not at all clear and your desired output does not agree with the code you show. For `window=2`, for instance, how can you have `2` and `4` in your result, and how do the values get doubled or tripled?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've added more explanation to the question. Hopefully, making it more clear. Gladly ask more questions. It's probably better not to look at the code for now since I don't know how to do it either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot understand from the explanation. I hope someone comes along who can. Good luck!

Comment: Your 2 results (windows 2 and 3) have length of 17 whereas your input has length of 16. Is that correct?

Comment: @Stev good catch, no, the length should be the same. I fixed it now.

Comment: You're original list doesn't seem to matter, you just need amount of negatives, zeros, and positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly, and all the indices are always ordered, I would use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy as np

def bin_list(l, width):
    a = np.array(l)
    a[a>0] = (a[a>0]+(width-1))//width
    a[a<0] = (a[a<0])//width
    return list(a)

l = [i for i in range(-9,0)] + [0,0] + [i for i in range(1,10)]

print(l)
print(bin_list(l,2))
print(bin_list(l,3))
print(bin_list(l,4))
```

This gives:

```
[-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[-5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
[-3, -3, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[-3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

If getting a `list` as result is an unnecessary constraint, you can change `return list(a)` to `return a`.

Comment: I was just about to post this! Kudos. OP doesn't notice original list doesn't matter - you can randomize and sort `l` and this will work.

Comment: this works, although `list(a)` didn't work, instead `a.tolist()` did.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the list into two sections, left and right. Then work on both separately and concatenate them at the end.

```
def binlist(startlist, window):

    idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(startlist) if j == 0]

    left  = startlist[:idx[0]]
    right = startlist[idx[-1] + 1:]

    newleft  = []
    newright = []

    counter = -1
    for i, _ in enumerate(left[::-1], 1):
        newleft.append(counter)
        if i % window == 0:
            counter -= 1

    newleft = newleft[::-1]

    counter  = 1
    for i, _ in enumerate(right, 1):
        newright.append(counter)
        if i % window == 0:
            counter += 1

    final = newleft + [0 for i in idx] + newright

    return final

# your test lists:
print(binlist([-8,-7,-6,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2))
print(binlist([-8,-7,-6,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3))
```

Out:

```
[-4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[-3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for your examples but you will need to test it to make sure it generalises.

```
import numpy as np

window=3
array = np.array([-8,-7,-6,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
RH = np.ceil(array[np.where( array > 0 )]/window)
result = np.hstack([-1*RH[::-1],0,0,RH])
```